# Boost serialization of template derived class

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, polymorphism

I have a templated base class `Base` and a templated derived class `Derived` which I want to serialize.
The below simplified code compiles and run but do not serialize data members from base class.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

template<class U, class V>
struct Base {
    Base(U uu, V vv) : u(uu), v(vv) {}
    U u;
    V v;
};

template<class V, class T>
struct Derived : public Base<V, int>, public Base<V, std::string> {
    Derived(T tt) : Base<V, int>(2.0, 4), Base<V, std::string>(3.0, std::string("hello")), t(tt) {}
    T t;
};

// does not work
//BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived);

namespace boost { namespace serialization {

template<class Archive, class U, class V>
void serialize(Archive & ar, Base<U,V> &obj, const unsigned int version) {
    ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(obj.u);
    ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(obj.v);
}

template<class Archive, class V, class T>
void serialize(Archive & ar, Derived<V,T> &obj, const unsigned int version) {
    boost::serialization::make_nvp("Base1", 
        boost::serialization::base_object<Base<V, int>>(obj) );
    boost::serialization::make_nvp("Base2", 
        boost::serialization::base_object<Base<V, std::string>>(obj) );
    // does not work
    // ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base<V, int>); 
    // ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base<V, std::string>);
    ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(obj.t);
}

}} // end namespace

int main() {
    Derived<double, int> a(10);

    std::ostringstream archive_ostream;
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(archive_ostream);
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a); 
    std::cout << archive_ostream.str() << std::endl;
}
```

**Demo : <kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82b650e83563cd1c)</kbd>**

Output is only :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="12">
<a class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <obj.t>10</obj.t>
</a>
```

So how can I get the serialization of `Base::u` and `Base::v` ? I have tried using `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived);` without success.

*Bonus question* : How can I also use the macro `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP` in this case ?

Comment: I will look at the bonus question later, when I have time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to actually write the NVP to the archive:

```
ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Base1", boost::serialization::base_object<Base<V, int>>(obj) );
ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Base2", boost::serialization::base_object<Base<V, std::string>>(obj) );
```

With that changed, it now prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="12">
<a class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <Base1 class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <obj.u>2.00000000000000000e+00</obj.u>
        <obj.v>4</obj.v>
    </Base1>
    <Base2 class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <obj.u>3.00000000000000000e+00</obj.u>
        <obj.v>hello</obj.v>
    </Base2>
    <obj.t>10</obj.t>
</a>
```

See **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85ca9df7e17de69f)</kbd>**

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

template<class U, class V>
struct Base {
    Base(U uu, V vv) : u(uu), v(vv) {}
    U u;
    V v;
};

template<class V, class T>
struct Derived : public Base<V, int>, public Base<V, std::string> {
    Derived(T tt) : Base<V, int>(2.0, 4), Base<V, std::string>(3.0, std::string("hello")), t(tt) {}
    T t;
};

// does not work
//BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived);

namespace boost { namespace serialization {

template<class Archive, class U, class V>
void serialize(Archive & ar, Base<U,V> &obj, const unsigned int /*version*/) {
    ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(obj.u);
    ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(obj.v);
}

template<class Archive, class V, class T>
void serialize(Archive & ar, Derived<V,T> &obj, const unsigned int /*version*/) {
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Base1", boost::serialization::base_object<Base<V, int>>(obj) );
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Base2", boost::serialization::base_object<Base<V, std::string>>(obj) );
    // does not work
    // ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base<V, int>); 
    // ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base<V, std::string>);
    ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(obj.t);
}

}} // end namespace

int main() {
    Derived<double, int> a(10);

    std::ostringstream archive_ostream;
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(archive_ostream);
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a); 
    std::cout << archive_ostream.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sehe (again ! :) for your answer but I do not understand. I have precised that in `void serialize(Archive & ar, Derived<V,T> &obj, const unsigned int version)`

Comment: See the full example :)

Comment: Oh thank you I feel dumb... I have reproduced badly my problem since I did not forget the `ar &` in my real code.... *sigh*

Answer (score 3):

I only answer the "bonus" question since @sehe already answered the main one:

In order to use `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP`, `serialize` must be a member function (see the definition in [`nvp.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/serialization/nvp.hpp)).

The following works: I had to typedef the Base classes to make the macro work:

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar,  const unsigned int version)
{

    typedef Base<V, int> Base1; 
    typedef Base<V, std::string> Base2; 

    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base1);
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(Base2);

    ar& BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(t);
}
```

See 
<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a43bbc84ade645a8)</kbd>